# Spark recommendation ALS nullpointer exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build an ALS model using Spark.mllib.recommendation. 
I am getting a null pointer exception. 
I do not see any null values in the columns I am using. help needed.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS

val path = "DataPath"
val data = spark.read.json(path)

data.printSchema()

data.createOrReplaceTempView("reviews")

val raw_reviews = spark.sql("Select reviewerID, cast(asin as int) as ProductID,  overall from reviews")

raw_reviews.printSchema()

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer


val stringindexer = new StringIndexer()
      .setInputCol("reviewerID")
      .setOutputCol("userID")
  val modelc = stringindexer.fit(raw_reviews)
  val  df = modelc.transform(raw_reviews)

val Array(training,test) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.8,0.2))

val als = new ALS().setMaxIter(5).setRegParam(0.01).setUserCol("userID").setItemCol("ProductID").setRatingCol("overall")

val model = als.fit(training)
```

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 30.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 30.0 (TID 94, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 1 is null

Comment: It would be helpful if the results of the intermediate variables can be checked.